# What does '0..°' mean in UML?

Tags: uml

An analysis from a colleague with UML diagrams contains the following:

```
0..°
```

I'm familiar with 0..* and such but not with the previous. Any ideas? Is it a typo? It's used throughout the document.

Comment: I guess it’s a typo.

Comment: never heard about it before so I guess it's a typo too...

Comment: Mistakenly typed `*` as `&deg;`, haha.

Comment: It's a typo. The answer won't help anyone but you. SO questions should be useful to more than just one person. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196985/232821

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this appears as a multiplicity: It's a typo or some sort of conversion error. According to the [UML spec](http://www.omg.org/cgi-bin/doc?formal/05-07-04), the upper bound of a multiplicity is of type UnlimitedNatural, and

> A LiteralUnlimitedNatural is shown
>   either as a sequence of digits or as
>   an asterisk (*), where an asterisk
>   denotes  unlimited (and not infinity).

Comment: Hi@Michael Borgwardt .as I read in UML certification book that the UnlimitedNatural is Infinite set of natural numbers. what do you mean by not infinity?

Comment: @Andrew: It's a quote from the UML spec, so you'd have to ask its authors what they meant. I suspect that someone got confused because in the definition of UnlimitedNatural it even says (in apparent contradiction) "The value infinity may be shown using an asterisk (‘*’)".